# axios post to find out if data is valid

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vee-validate

OK I am at the end of my day and I am not thinking straight. So this is what I have...

a Laravel controller, send it a username, and it tells me if the username is available, and if it isnt, it gives me a 422 code

```
public function checkUsername(Request $request) {
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        ])->validate();
    
        return response()->json([
            'valid' => true,
            'data' => [
                'message' => 'Username is available!'
            ]
        ], 200);
    }
```

Example of valid response:

```
{"valid":true,"data":{"message":"Username is available!"}}%
```

The curl to test is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "bossryan"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checkusername
```

Next: I have a frontend Vue using Vee-validate. It does a bunch of things, but I need to add this latest validation into the mix, so if the username is taken (I don't get the valid response from above, it needs to reply with "This username is already taken"

```
validateUsername(value) {
                // if the field is empty
                if (!value) {
                    return 'This field is required';
                }
                const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{4,20}$/i;
                if (!regex.test(value)) {
                    return 'This must be a minimum of 4 characters';
                }
                return true;
            },
```

This is the axios I created but it isnt working:

```
const isUnique = (value) => {
                    return axios.post('/api/checkusername', { email: value }).then((response) => {
                        // Notice that we return an object containing both a valid property and a data property.
                        return {
                        valid: response.data.valid,
                        data: {
                            message: response.data.message
                            }
                        };
                    });
                };
```

I know I need to add in axios, but I am just having a heck of a time setting it up and my mind keeps rushing around. I am just looking for someone who can just help me plug in the axios request above //All is good, so I can finish this up.

THANKS FOR THE HELP COMMUNITY!

Comment: In your dev-tools _Network_ panel, you should see the POST request being made to `/api/checkusername`, right? You should also be able to see that the response status is 422. Are you saying that if you click on that request and open the _Response_ tab, that it's completely empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vee-validate seems to want a resolved promise for async validation. Axios will reject the promise if the status is >= 400 so you need to handle that accordingly.

Assuming when validation fails that the response body matches the same `{ valid, data: { message } }` format, you'd want something like the following

```js
const isUnique = (name) => 
  axios.post("/api/checkusername", { name })
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .catch(err => ({ // resolve with error details
      valid: err.response?.data?.valid ?? false,
      data: {
        // get the message from the response if it exists
        message: err.response?.data?.data?.message ?? "Validation failed"
      }
    }));

export default {
  methods: {
    async validateUsername(value) {
      // do your synchronous checks as per question

      const check = await isUnique(value);
      return check.valid || check.data.message;
    }
  }
}
```

This will provide a generic message *"Validation failed"* if the 422 response body doesn't match expectations.

Comment: Thank you Phil - This is what I was missing was the async part. I do need to clean it up some because I want to limit the request onBlur (but thats easy), this at least gave me what I was looking for!!!